# Can a server detect whether the request is coming from an extension or a browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

Is there a way to detect that whether a URI request is coming from a browser or from the extension?

Can you please comment on IE 7+ and Firefox extensions separately?

Thank you for your responses and for helping me out.

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no spoof free way to do this. Most browser extensions have the same User Agent as the browser. Therefore, I don't know of a way. What you could do is invoke some exotic feature that the extension will have trouble dealing with.